# How to create an automatic timer?

Tags: automator, catalina

On macOS Catalina 10.15.2 I'm currently trying to use Automator to:

- Get current time
- Get current day (Mon,Tues,ect.)
- Fetch a time based on current time for each period at my school, from a list in a text file
- Use a function to subtract current time from variable
- Display / Project onto / Create a window displaying the output of the function

Example for a table of times:

- "1" = "35640"
- "2" = "41820"
- "3" = "44220"
- "L" = "48300"
- "32" = "49500"
- "4" = "55200"

The time was converted from military to seconds, for example 4 was 3:20pm.
I'd calculate which time to use, for example 2 ends at 11:37am, if the current time (in seconds is less than 41820, and greater than 35640, it'd take a localized string of 2. Then take the current time, say 11:20am (40800), and subtract it from 41820, giving 1020, convert back into hh:mm:ss, then displaying. I've never used Applescript and am trying to learn it. The most I can do right now is hello world level coding.

As a file this looks like this:

```
1; 35640
2; 41820
3; 44220
L; 48300
32; 49500
4; 55200
```

Apologies for being assumingly frustrating, I came from Ti-Basic and haven't done any *real* coding

Comment: Although it could display a dialog with some kind of result, Automator is more of a batch processing kind of thing.

Comment: Danny Budnick, I don't have a referral sheet, sorry, but what you've asked probably can be done in **Automator** , and could also be done in **AppleScript** by itself. However, without knowing what's in the text file it hard to say what's the best way to go about it. Any question containing an unknown variable (the context of the text file) makes it difficult to answer!

Comment: It would just include a list of times when my current period ends, most likely converted to seconds. At my school on tuesdays and thursdays or schedule slightly changes so it would be two lists of 5 timestamps.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the text file so people can provide solutions which fit your file format?

Comment: Are external links against the rules? Or would it be easier / not clutter(y) to put it right in the discussion?

Comment: Both are ok, even though I would prefer a small sample directly as part of the question.

Comment: Apologies if you already received a notification for the edit to the post, I'm unfamiliar with this site.

Comment: No worries, some iterations on such posts are not unusual. If you want to notify somebody, please use @nohillside etc. I've edited your question to add *my* understanding of how the file would like like (the format you seen when opening the file in Textedit or similar). Please fix whatever is wrong.

Comment: Also, there are two slots called "3" and two slots with the same time. If this is a typo, please fix, otherwise explain how that should be handled. And: what happens after 49500, how can we now when the last lesson ends?

Comment: You said "At my school on tuesdays and thursdays or schedule slightly changes so it would be two lists of 5 timestamps" and there are now two different lists in the OP in different formats with two number threes and three and four showing the same time. Please clarify the need and or use of two lists, clarify the format without bullets, showing the actual content of the two files!

Comment: You also said "The time was converted from military to seconds, for example 4 was 3:20pm.", well "3:20pm" is not military time. In military time It would be 1520 or 1520 hours.

Comment: @user3439894 | 4 was a typo, and I start 3rd period, go to lunch, then finish 3rd, and I didn't think into the second 3 being an error.
When I stated it was converted from military, I meant to have an example, as in "here after calculating to something the program can use, I got 55200, which *was* 3:20pm. I assumed you'd know I changed 3:20pm to 1520, then to seconds. There is only one list, its an example, the second list is just the usual time +- 15 minutes, but only on Tuesdays and Thursdays.

Comment: @nohillside | For when the last period ends, I'd just have a comparison of whether its after 55220 (3:20pm) and before 29700 (8:15am). If it is, the program would just display nothing until after 29700, then (assumingely) infinitely loop.

Comment: After brute forcing and trying tons of things I've just decided to not make this, or atleast in Applescript. Don't know how to lock this thread so-.